# JWT Token Validation using public key

Tags: c#, jwt, x509certificate2

I'm trying to validate my JWT using public key but I'm getting exception as shown below; Could you please help me into this.

Error while calling below line;

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(key));
```

Code Snippet is :

```
var publicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCiHpDUH0AtBRNvqEblOeVyviJZ 4UV2LwGiWrSIysK4sL3mToAgDz11MWvo+yycMmwjCiFAQgF4vspzTAexJ6+ZIvbi WRGdJiaqqja2xMRZkDJuJF2rN5CrbNhKrmyM1+weud2jhIHXdxkbJb89oRrbOvfh yWuY8J7pPFiTnzH9sQIDAQAB -----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

                var key =
                    "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCiHpDUH0AtBRNvqEblOeVyviJZ 4UV2LwGiWrSIysK4sL3mToAgDz11MWvo+yycMmwjCiFAQgF4vspzTAexJ6+ZIvbi WRGdJiaqqja2xMRZkDJuJF2rN5CrbNhKrmyM1+weud2jhIHXdxkbJb89oRrbOvfh yWuY8J7pPFiTnzH9sQIDAQAB";

                var token = "eyJraWQiOiIwZTIwZjU0NC00ZmQzLTQ4YTYtOGUzMi01NWUwNTJiMDI2ODIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.jC7-bVSaxAGNLk2d--8fksH_9PKgo3TgIALynlwkUOC3AE79MrLaqCRGp0yT2wqfFJ5kRGJFyUu_EP3_3YE6d4XS5yhghaFrkewwUHt4eV56qYOFf4RIC_CiX_OcK8vXSEpeMt6jKN-f7iDP6fo2NqmYH07_ZJM0LXc7S5WAQDQ";

                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(key));
                var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    IssuerSigningTokens = new[] { new X509SecurityToken(certificate) }
                };
                SecurityToken validatedSecurityToken = null;
                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                try
                {
                    handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedSecurityToken);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late for you I guess but for anybody else dealing with that:

I guess the error is: `CryptographicException: Object not found`

This is as you try to initialize a full X509Certificate with just the public key. This is part of it, but many other things are missing like expiration date and subject.

You will have to initialize the X509Certificate2 using a full certificate indicated by the following lines, but remove them before converting them from Base64, so that only the content gets decoded:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(content)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```